# python base class using super() causes argument error

Tags: python

I've written my base class and a subclass however i get errors im not familiar with when trying to use pythons newest class creation with Super. However if i replace **'super(Camera)'** with **'Node'** it works fine.

```
""" 
Base class  
"""
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name, attributes, children):
        self.name = name
        self.attributes = attributes if attributes is not None else {}
        self.children = children if children is not None else []

"""
sub-class
"""
class Camera(Node):
    def __init__(self, name="", attributes=None, children=None, enabled=True):
        super(Camera).__init__(self, name=name, attributes=attributes, children=children)
        self.enabled = enabled
```

Comment: One-argument `super` has its uses, but I admit I don't understand the exact error it raises here. It's intended for calling class methods; perhaps trying to invoke an instance method is what breaks things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should do:

```
super(Camera, self).__init__(name=name, attributes=attributes, children=children)
```